# VSS -> TFS conversion - best methods for converting single directories?

Tags: tfs, visual-sourcesafe

Running Visual Source Safe 2005 and TFS 2010. The 2003 server that VSS is running on is being retired, and the information I've been told is that VSS can't run on server 2008 (anyone want to help declare that flummery?) so I need to migrate our sizable archives.

The conversion tool that Microsoft offers seems to have done a passably good job of getting the majority of my files, but a couple of projects seem to have been missed, purportedly a File or project not found error, though I see them in VSS.

I'd like to try converting them again, but I see no way to convert selected directories in a project, the tool seems to be an all or nothing past the selection of the project.  And due to poor design, or perhaps just many years of use, some of those projects are HUGE, and I'd much rather find a way to pick and choose than try again from scratch.

I already have local copies of all the files, and even a local copy of the database files should I indeed find a way to get the running on another server.  But getting all the files converted from VSS does seem the best method, so I'm hoping I can go in and just re-try the directories that failed.

Comment: FYI TFS2010 is already at end of life https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?sort=PN&alpha=team%20foundation%20server%202010&Filter=FilterNO If you can you should upgrade to a currently supported version of TFS.

Answer (score 0):

VSS is well out of support and frankly it is a liability if your database is more than about 3GB in size (which they all are!) so a migration is the way to go.  Kritner is correct that you should also think about bumping up your TFS version asap too.

You need to specify your VSS projects or folders in the `<ProjectMap>` section of the Analyze settings file.  Then in the migration settings file you'll map them to your TFS projects like this:

```
  <ProjectMap>
              <Project Source="$/Core/Libs" Destination="$/CoreTeamProject/Libs"></Project>
              <Project Source="$/ProjectA" Destination="$/ClientTeamProject/ProjectA"></Project>
              <Project Source="$/ProjectB" Destination="$/ClientTeamProject/ProjectB"></Project>
         </ProjectMap>
```

You'll probably find that in a huge VSS database there is some corruption which means the migration tool will miss some things.  Run Analyze (-v4 -f flags if memory serves) against your data dir.

Another option is to use SSARC to archive off some of the huge amount of VSS history and only migrate some of it.

[VSSUpgrade command-prompt tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253090.aspx)